# Selenium ide: Dynamic value mismatch issue

Tags: dynamic, selenium, ide

I am new to selenium ide and facing the following issue:

I have a dynamic value coming in Target for one click command. The value is something like: 
XYZ_1234098:out. The numeric values keeps on changing. 
I have tried both contains and starts-with but no success.

I have tried using regular expression but i guess we can't use them in selenium ide.

Kindly suggest any possible solution for the issue.

Comment: id="_RapidSureCRM_WAR_RapidSureCRM_INSTANCE_zm2L_:editform:mainmenu:menuitems:RISK_MODULE_COVERAGE1832534:link" href="javascript:;" class="iceCmdLnk"><span id="_RapidSureCRM_WAR_RapidSureCRM_INSTANCE_zm2L_:editform:mainmenu:menuitems:RISK_MODULE_COVERAGE1832534:out"

Comment: the id: RapidSureCRM_WAR_RapidSureCRM_INSTANCE_zm2L:editform:mainmenu:menuitems:RI‌​SK_MODULE_COVERAGE1832534:out     needs to be modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that in your case it is **id=XYZ_1234098** for some tag. You can try something like

```
//*[contains(@id,'XYZ')]
```

Comment: hey abhi, i have already tried the contain but its not working.

Comment: As per your updated question this should work.
//span[contains(@id,':out')]